# User cannot access a file after setting an ACL

Tags: permissions, group, acl

I cannot enter a directory after creation in a folder with an ACL:
I am attempting to limit rwx access to a folder for just a single group and no one else. I would like to be able to add new users to a group and have them gain access to a directory.

This is what I have done so far

1. `mkdir /mnt/files`
2. `cp /media/usb0/backup/* /mnt/files`
3. `chgrp filers /mnt/files`
4. `chmod -R g+s /mnt/files`
5. `setfacl -b /mnt/files  # to remove user and other`
6. `setfacl -R -d -m g:filers:rwx /mnt/files`
7. `getfacl /mnt/files`

   ```
   # file: mnt/files/
   # owner: root
   # group: filers
   user::---
   group::rwx
   other::---
   default:user::---
   default:group::rwx
   default:group:filers:rwx
   default:mask::rwx
   default:other::---
   ```

So far everything looks good . . .

8. `cd /mnt/files`
9. `mkdir test`
10. `ls -l`

    ```
    d---rws---+ 2 jimmy filers 4096 Nov 28 14:32 test
    ```
11. cd test

    ```
    -bash: cd: test/: Permission denied
    ```

Any reason I can't enter the folder I just created?

12. `getfacl ./test`

    ```
    # file: test
    # owner: jimmy
    # group: filers
    # flags: -s-
     user::---
     group::rwx
     group:filers:rwx
      mask::rwx
     other::---
     default:user::---
     default:group::rwx
     default:group:filers:rwx
     default:mask::rwx
     default:other::---
    ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any particular reason why owner doesn't have full permissions?  Owner's permissions take precedence.  As a root, you can do anything, but as a regular user if you remove rwx for a directory you own, you cannot enter it since you don't have a search bit (x).  It does not matter that you are in a group that have permissions.  Right know, user jimmy cannot enter his directory, but paradoxically just about any other user in a group filers can. I'd say step 6 should be `setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx,g:filers:rwx /mnt/files`

Comment: This fixed it, I was unaware that not having X on user superseded the x in the group. Why wouldn't execute permissions in group work for a folder assigned to that group? Either way knowing that the user must have individual permissions fixed my issue. I went with: setfacl -R -d -m u::--x,g::rwx /mnt/files

Comment: I would up-vote this but apparently I don't have enough internet karma to donate karma, I apologize but thank you non-the-less

Comment: @omgimdrunk you are welcome.  I believe you can still accept my answer if you wish: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png